# $L^2[a,b] = \text{Cl} (C[a, b]) $?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, continuity, proof-explanation, lebesgue-integral

We say a complex function $f \in L^2[a,b]$ on $X$ if $f$ is measurable and if $\int_X |f|^2 d \mu< \infty$. On the other hand for any $f \in L^2[a,b]$ is a limit point Of $ C[a, b]) $. So $C[a, b]) \subset L^2[a,b] \subset \text{Cl} (C[a, b]) $. So how the statement Theorem 11.38 Rudin's Analysis is true? :

> The continuous functions form a dense subset of $L^2[a,b] $.

That is to say $\text{Cl} (C[a, b])  \subset  L^2[a,b]$.

Comment: No! A dense subset $A$ of $X$ is to say that $Cl(A) = X$

Comment: I remember reading that proof. An intuitive way to see it is remember that simple functions are dense. But simple functions are approximable by step functions (characteristics of intervals instead of arbitrary measurable sets) and finally a characteristic of an interval is clearly approximable by continuos functions.

Comment: @HFKy I couldn't fix my problem yet. The proof says  $L^2[a,b] \subset \text{Cl} (C[a, b]) $ but the theorem says equality. how to prove the converse to complete the proof?

Comment: Ahh! Now I understand your problem. If $A\subset X$ then $Cl(A)$ is a subset of $X$. The closure of a set in a space $X$ doesn't make sense outside the space $X$, because $X$ establishes the notions of convergence!. More concretely, $Cl(A)$ is by definition the points of $X$ that are approximable (with the notion given by $X$) with elements of $A$.

Comment: @HFKy, No the closure of $C[a, b]$ is in the set of *all* functions on[a, b] and the closure of $C[a, b]$ may be bigger than $L^2[a, b] $ (?)

Comment: No, because in the set of all functions on $[a,b]$ doesn't make sense $\int_{[a,b]} f(x)^2 \ dx$. In the set $L^2([a,b])$ one can define $\lVert f \rVert ^2 =\int_{[a,b]} f(x)^2 \ dx$ and this norm induces a notion of convergence, $f_i \to f$ iff $\lVert f-f_i \rVert \to 0$. Outside $L^2$ you don't have this notion. This is what I said in the previous comment but with a generic space $X$

Comment: @HFKy uncountable thanks :)

Comment: Once you have this space $X = L^2$, the closure of a set $A\subset X$ depends on the notion of convergence that there is on X. Of course that maybe $A$ is a subset of another space $Y$, and then the closure (using $Y$) may be different, even if the set $Y = X$ (they are not equal as spaces)